# Python: cx_Oracle does not like how I am entering date

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to do a simple select all query in python using the Cx_oracle module. When I do a select all for the first ten rows in a table I am able to print our the output. However when I do a select all for the first ten rows for a specific date in the table all that gets printed out is a blank list like this: [].

Here is the query select all query that prints out all the results:

```
sql_query = "select * from table_name fetch first 10 rows only"
cur = db_eng.OpenCursor()
db_eng.ExecuteQuery(cur, sql_query)
result = db_eng.FetchResults(cur)
print(result)
```

The above query works and is able to print out the results.

Here is the query that I am having trouble with and this query below works in sql developer:

```
sql_query = "select * from table_name where requested_time = '01-jul-2021' fetch first 10 rows only"
cur = db_eng.OpenCursor()
db_eng.ExecuteQuery(cur, sql_query)
result = db_eng.FetchResults(cur)
print(result)
```

I also tried this way where I define the date outside of the query.

```
specific_date = '01-jul-2021'
sql_query = "select * from table_name where requested_time = '{0}' fetch first 10 rows only".format(specific_date)
cur = db_eng.OpenCursor()
db_eng.ExecuteQuery(cur, sql_query)
result = db_eng.FetchResults(cur)
print(result)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `where` clause name the column that contains the date you are looking for, as in `where some_column = '01-jul-2021'?

Comment: I forgot to put that in my query for the example above for the actual query I actually did specify the column.

Comment: what about rewriting the query by using the condition `requested_time = date'2021-07-01'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle dates have a *time portion*. The query

```
select * from table_name where requested_time = '01-jul-2021' fetch first 10 rows only
```

Will only give you the rows for which the value for the column requested_time is 01-jul-2021 *00:00*. Chances are that you have other rows for which there is a time portion as well.
To cut off the time portion there are several options. Note that I explicitly added the  a TO_DATE function to the date - you're assuming that the database is *expecting* a *dd-mon-yyyy* format and successfully will do the implicit conversion but it's safer to let the database know.

1. **TRUNC** truncate the column - this will remove the time portion

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE TRUNC(requested_time) = TO_DATE('01-jul-2021','DD-mon-YYYY')
 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

2. Format the column date to the same format as the date you supplied and compare the resulting string:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE TO_CHAR(requested_time,'DD-mon-YYYY') = '01-jul-2021'
 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Example:

```
pdb1--KOEN>create table test_tab(requested_time DATE);

Table TEST_TAB created.

pdb1--KOEN>BEGIN
  2  INSERT INTO test_tab(requested_time) VALUES (TO_DATE('08-AUG-2021 00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'));
  3  INSERT INTO test_tab(requested_time) VALUES (TO_DATE('08-AUG-2021 01:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'));
  4  INSERT INTO test_tab(requested_time) VALUES (TO_DATE('08-AUG-2021 02:10','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'));
  5  END;
  6  /


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

pdb1--KOEN>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_tab WHERE requested_time = TO_DATE('08-AUG-2021','DD-MON-YYYY');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
--only 1 row. That is the rows with time 00:00. Other rows are ignored

pdb1--KOEN>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_tab WHERE TRUNC(requested_time) = TO_DATE('08-AUG-2021','DD-MON-YYYY');

-- all rows

  COUNT(*)
----------
         3
```